# Laravel Send "create password email" after admin created new user from Admin Dashboard

Tags: php, laravel

I have an admin dashboard. User can't create a user account by himself only admin has the rights to do it. But he will only create a user with "username" and "email". What I want to achieve is when he created a new user to send a email to the user email address with his "username" and "email" + button or link to create his password. I was trying to search about customizing the default reset password functioanlity but I failed. Can someone provide some easier approach for this ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is pretty easy, and in my opinion if you start thinking instead of "how to customise existing functionality" to "how to create my own functionality", you can figure it out by yourself in no time.

You can do it for example like this, that after signing up the user, you can send within the registration email a link to "set my passwowrd" and the link might look like https://example.com/user/finish-registration?hash=sadfjasdnfdaisfnsduff

```
    //migration
    Schema::create($table, function() => {
        $table->string("set_password_hash");
        $table->string("username");
    });

    //signup method
    public function signUpUser(Request $request) {
        
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $request->input("username");
        $user->email = $request->input("email");

        $user->set_password_hash = Hash::make(20); //or some random hash generator

        //set as empty string
        $user->password = "";
        $user->save();

        $signupMail = new SignupMail($user);
        $signupMail->send();
    }

    public function setPasswordView(Request $request) {
        $user = User::where("set_password_hash", $request->input("hash"))->first();

        if($user) {
            if($user->password === "") {
                //display a form for the user to create his own password
                return view("user.setPassword");
            } else {
                //the password has already been set    
            }
        }

        //fail or something
    }
```